# Qt: How to close application after starting a new process?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I am starting a new process from my application using **QProcess::startDetached()**. After this new process is started, I want my application to exit. How do I do that?

Comment: @N1ghtLight. A little more detail. I am building on **Mac**. After the new process gets started, my application's window disappeares but remains docked in the dock. I want the application to be fully closed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [qApp](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#qApp) macro as following: `qApp->quit();`

`QApplication` or `QCoreApplication` header should be included.

void `QCoreApplication`::[quit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#quit) () [static slot]

> Tells the application to exit with return code 0 (success). Equivalent
>   to calling QCoreApplication::exit(0).

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, that calling `QProcess::startDetached()` doesn't mean that new process is started. You should check returned value of this method:

```
bool isStarted = QProcess::startDetached(commandString);
if(isStarted)
    {
    qApp->quit();
    }
```